# Display json variable via jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want a variable of the json file to be displayed (Date) but it does not seen to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
   {
        $.getJSON("http://json-head.appspot.com/?url=http://www.trinum.com/ibox/chatel/images/photofull.jpg&callback=?", function(data)
         {
           $.each(data.headers, function(i,item)
           {
              if(i < 2)
              {
                 $("body").append("+item.Date+");
              }
           });

         });        
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is your JSON response structure, `headers` is only an object, and with the [$.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) function, you are iterating through this object members (*Content-Length, Via, etc...*), if `headers` is intended to store more than one object, you should use the array notation "`[]`" on it:

```
{
    "status_code": 200, 
    "ok": true, 
    "headers": [{
        "Content-Length": "7068", 
        "Via": "HTTP\/1.1 GWA", 
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET", 
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes", 
        "X-Google-Cache-Control": "remote-fetch", 
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS\/6.0", 
        "Last-Modified": "Tue, 06 Feb 2007 07:57:38 GMT", 
        "ETag": "\"8b5f5c78c449c71:2c6a\"", 
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache", 
        "Date": "Sun, 19 Jul 2009 05:51:42 GMT", 
        "Content-Type": "image\/jpeg"
    }]
};
```

By doing so, [$.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) will iterate through the entire objects defined within the `headers` array.

The array notation begins with `[` (*left bracket*), ends with `]` (*right bracket*), and the values are separated with `,` (*comma*) :

[image: JSON Array Notation]

For more information about JSON syntax and structure check [this site](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just google for javascript+dump and you will find some equivalents of php's print_r for javaScript.

This is one example (from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others )

```
/dump_function_php_print_r.php )
/**
 * Function : dump()
 * Arguments: The data - array,hash(associative array),object
 *    The level - OPTIONAL
 * Returns  : The textual representation of the array.
 * This function was inspired by the print_r function of PHP.
 * This will accept some data as the argument and return a
 * text that will be a more readable version of the
 * array/hash/object that is given.
 * Docs: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php
 */
function dump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
        dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}
```

Comment: Add a hasOwnProperty check inside the for..in loop and this works out pretty well. I was able to use it with jquery.terminal for outputting json objects into the console for debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a parser on the client that understands date format the date isn’t parsed and .getJSON() won’t parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON takes 3 arguments in the order url, data, callback. So in this case, you would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("http://json-head.appspot.com/?url=http://www.trinum.com/ibox/chatel/images/photofull.jpg&callback=?", null, function(data){
  $.each(data.headers, function(i,item){
   if(i < 2){
    $("body").append("+item.Date+");
   }
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is your client-side sent as Date ? 
because sometimes i found that instead of sending as String, it render as javascript Date (it is timestamp)

so you need to convert like this:

```
var yourDate = new Date(item.Date);
```

the complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
   {
        $.getJSON("http://json-head.appspot.com/?url=http://www.trinum.com/ibox/chatel/images/photofull.jpg&callback=?", function(data)
         {
           $.each(data.headers, function(i,item)
           {
              if(i < 2)
              {
                 $("body").append(new Date(item.Date));
              }
           });

         });        
    });

</script>
```